# Draw canvas on captured image and save react-native

Tags: android, react-native

Here I am wondering about how to draw

- Draw Freehand
- Draw Lines
- Draw Polylines
- Draw Shapes
- Circles
- Rectangles
- Add SVG Stickers
- Select Color
- Select line thickness

On image which captured using camera or selected from gallery and save this edit image file as new file in react native

Comment: Did you end up finding anything that does this for you? I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas in order to allow drawing on a users image and exporting that, but cannot place stickers on those images unfortunately.